# How do I convert an IP address into an integer between 1 and 3?

Tags: math, ip

I'm not a mathematician so this may be a stupid question...but - is there any way to translate IP addresses into integers between 1 and 3, whereby there will A) be an equal distribution of 1's, 2's and 3's and B) each IP address will always translate to the same integer? (in essence, a hash).

I'm using 3 as an example - ideally I'd like the range limit to be customizable.

```
$highest_allowed_integer = 3;
$integer = get_evenly_distributed_but_always_identical_integer($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$highest_allowed_integer);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Treat the entire IPv4 address as a number in base 256 (that means 4.3.2.1 would translate to `(4 << 24) + (3 << 16) + (2 << 8) + 1`), then mod it by 3, and then add 1.

On a little digression, you might want to look into the concept of [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Comment: plus one for being the only answer so far that points out the need to add 1 to the modulus result ^^

Answer (score 1):

`ip2long ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])%3;`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the distribution of IP addresses or how important it is that they be uniform, but one thing you could try would be to add up all of the digits in the IP address and then mod that by 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (as long as you're not too strict about what "equal distribution" means).

The simple way other people have already suggested involves 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic where 3 is the "modulus".